# I have 3 different classes, with the same method names. Need to check before usage and apply the right instance of them c#

Tags: c#

I have 3 different classes but the same methods inside them. Need to check before usage and apply the right instance of them c#. The calling methods are the same but different logic inside. I need to be able to call the right instance at the right time. I tried everything and it appears that I am failing.

Interface is not an option because these assemblies come in the form of DLLs. I dont have the source code for them.

```
public VersionAssembly240 obj1 = new VersionAssembly240();
public VersionAssembly250 obj2 = new VersionAssembly250();
public VersionAssembly260 obj3 = new VersionAssembly260();

void Main()
{
    ChooseRightInstance(null, obj2, null, "v25");

}

public void ChooseRightInstance(VersionAssembly240 obj1, VersionAssembly250 obj2, VersionAssembly260 obj3, string version)
{
    if (version == "v24")
    {
        var obj = obj1;
    }
    else if (version == "v25")
    {
        var obj = obj2;
    }
    else
    {
        var obj = obj3;
    }

    //I need to be able to access the obj var somce the 3 classess have the same access methods
    obj
}

//for testing
public class VersionAssembly260
{
    public string example()
    {
        return "v26";
    }
}

public class VersionAssembly250
{
    public string example()
    {
        return "v25";
    }
}

public class VersionAssembly240
{
    public string example()
    {
        return "v24";
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant do that... its not how this works. You also cannot instantiate a variable in the if /else statement and return it outside of it. Interfaces are perhaps the way to go with this ... not assemblies

Answer (score 3):

You can try below

```
// make abstract base class
public abstract class BaseVersionAssembly
{
    public abstract string example();
}

public class VersionAssembly260 : BaseVersionAssembly
{
    public override string example()
    {
        return "v26";
    }
}

public class VersionAssembly250 : BaseVersionAssembly
{
    public override string example()
    {
        return "v25";
    }
}

public class VersionAssembly240 : BaseVersionAssembly
{
    public override string example()
    {
        return "v24";
    }


}
```

ChooseRightInstance function

```
public string ChooseRightExample(BaseVersionAssembly obj)
{
    return obj.example();
}
```

Comment: yes, I understand that, but the method example() is just for testing purposes. There are a lot of methods under the respective assembly versions. This is a way but is not there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to crate an interface with method `example()` and different implementations for each class.

```
public interface IVersionAssembly
{
    string example();
}
```

Implement method `example()`

```
public class VersionAssembly260 : IVersionAssembly
{
    public string example()
    {
        return "v26";
    }
}

public class VersionAssembly250 : IVersionAssembly
{
    public string example()
    {
        return "v25";
    }
}

public class VersionAssembly240 : IVersionAssembly
{
    public string example()
    {
        return "v24";
    }
}
```

Now use interface `IVersionAssembly` in method `ChooseRightInstance`

```
public void ChooseRightInstance(VersionAssembly240 obj1, VersionAssembly250 obj2, VersionAssembly260 obj3, string version)
{
    IVersionAssembly obj;
    if (version == "v24")
    {
        obj = obj1;
    }
    else if (version == "v25")
    {
        obj = obj2;
    }
    else
    {
        obj = obj3;
    }

    obj.example();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially achieve this using an Interface, assuming that the real-world versions of these classes all have the same public methods.

Live demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/63hjQt

Code. See the comments inline for more info on each important part:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main() {
      VersionAssembly240 obj1 = new VersionAssembly240();
      VersionAssembly250 obj2 = new VersionAssembly250();
      VersionAssembly260 obj3 = new VersionAssembly260();
      ChooseRightInstance( null, obj2,  null ,  "v25" );
    }

    public static void ChooseRightInstance(VersionAssembly240 obj1, VersionAssembly250 obj2, VersionAssembly260 obj3, string version) 
    {
      IVersionAssembly obj; //declare the object outside the if, as an instance of the interface
      if (version == "v24")
      {
        obj = obj1;
      }
      else if (version == "v25")
      {
        obj = obj2;
      }
      else
      {
        obj = obj3;
      }

      Console.WriteLine(obj.example()); //can call the example() method because the interface defines it
    } 
}

//interface which defines the methods which all the classes must implement    
public interface IVersionAssembly
{
    string example();
}

//all the classes implement the interface, but within the methods they can use different concrete implementations
public class VersionAssembly260 : IVersionAssembly
{
    public string example()
    {
        return "v26";
    }
}

public class VersionAssembly250 : IVersionAssembly
{
    public string example()
    {
        return "v25";
    }
}

public class VersionAssembly240 : IVersionAssembly
{
    public string example()
    {
        return "v24";
    }
}
```

Here's the Microsoft guide to interfaces in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/

Comment: yes, I understand that, but the method example() is just for testing purposes. There are a lot of methods under the respective assembly versions. This is a way but is not there a better way to do this?

Comment: I dont know what the assemblies have in terms of methods etc. They come in the form of DLL only. Hence the reason I never wrote an interface.

Comment: Intellisense in Visual Studio can tell you what public methods they have (assuming they're .NET assemblies rather than COM/Win32). You don't need to worry about private ones, they are not considered when defining an interface. So if the public ones are all the same, as you stated in your original question, then an interface could work nicely. Problem is, if they're just in a DLL and you don't have the source code of the class, you can't change it to make the classes implement the interface. That was probably a detail you should have shared earlier...

Comment: ...so if you can't alter the source code, and there's no existing interface or base class which would link them together, then I think you are probably fundamentally out of luck with what you're trying to do - you can never coerce objects of different types into the same type in the way your original code is attempting. (Well, technically you _can_ - you could cast them all as `object` but that's useless because you can't then call any methods on them.)

Comment: pretty much yes, out of luck. you are correct. Thank you really for your dedication to help here.